# Only part of the object rendered in viewport cycles. Not a border problem. What is it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view

[image: only part of the face rendered]
I cant figure out why only part of his face is being rendered in viewport in cycles. Border is much bigger. The object is much bigger than rendered. You see on the picture. Any ideas? Bottom left is rendered in cycles.
All other objects are rendered fine, just only his head has this. When I rotate camera rendered is only part between observer and the same part of the face.